# Opening a jsp page onClick opens the page within the frame

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

The above navbar is npt.jsp & and below is the frame.
Onclick on the button viewProfile i tried to open home page ie root.jsp, instead opening hte page its opening the page within the frame.
I have attached the screenshots below. Kindly help me out

```
 <body>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><div       id="session">
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="mytestdata.jsp" target="frame">My TestData</a></li>
                <li><a href="myprofile.jsp" target="frame">My Profile</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
 <iframe name="frame" src="npt.jsp"></iframe>\
```

Onclicking myprofile its opening within the frame its an anchor tag  , but in MyProfile page when i click the button(on click home page shld be opened **NOT** within the frame)

Myprofile code :

```
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <h2><strong>  </strong></h2>                    
                            <p><small>Followers</small></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-success btn-block"><span class="fa fa-plus-circle"></span> Follow </button>
                        </div><!--/col-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <h2><strong></strong></h2>                    
                            <p><small>Following</small></p>
                            <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="openPage('root.jsp')"><span class="fa fa-user"></span> View Profile </button>
                        </div><!--/col-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <h2><strong></strong></h2>                    
                            <p><small>Snippets</small></p>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block"><span class="fa fa-gear"></span> Options </button>  
                        </div><!--/col-->
                    </div><!--/row-->
              </div><!--/panel-body-->
          </div><!--/panel-->
<script>
function openPage(pageURL){
    window.location.href = pageURL;
}
</script>
```

Comment: How on earth should anyone be able to answer a code question, just by looking at a screenshot? It would be pure guess.

Comment: <button class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="openPage('root.jsp')">
<script>
function openPage(pageURL){
 window.location.href = pageURL;
}
</script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<A HREF="profile.jsp" TARGET="_parent">View Profile</A>
```

or

```
<A HREF="profile.jsp" TARGET="_top">View Profile</A>
```

and if you are using javascript:

```
window.top.location.href = "profile.jsp";
```

In your case it will be:

```
<button class="btn btn-info btn-block" onclick="openPage('root.jsp')"> <script> function openPage(pageURL){ window.top.location.href = pageURL; } </script>
```

Comment: <input type="button" onclick='window.top.location.href = "profile.jsp";' />